# Share macvlan ip address with docker-compose container group

Tags: linux-networking, docker-compose

In a `docker-compose` container group, containers don't need addresses as they can communicate with each other using this pseudo-DNS provided by Docker only for the members of that group. Then, to communicate with the outside, it's the standard NAT regression affair Docker loves.

What if I'm using macvlan networking-based IP addressing though? How could I assign an address that's shared with the whole group instead of only to a single service of the group. All the examples and documentation I've found are not only not official but also apply the address at the service level in a compose file. There's never any mention or hint of other options.

If I'd move those lines with the IP address and away from the service and into the part that references the macvlan docker network in the compose file, and then leave the services as before so they use that NAT travesty but at least behind an independent address from the host's , would that work?

I found this snippet on GitHub that serves as an example:

```yaml
#
# macvlan def
docker network create -d macvlan \
    --subnet=192.168.0.0/24 \
    --gateway=192.168.0.1 \
    --ip-range=192.168.0.100/28 \
    -o parent=eth0 vdsm

#
# compose file
services:
  dsm:
    container_name: dsm
    ..<snip>..
    networks:
      vdsm:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.0.100  ╮
                                     │ ↙︎ MOVE SOMEWHERE DOWN HERE 
networks:       ╭────────────────────╯
  vdsm:         ↓ ← macvlan/EXT NETWORK REF
    external: true
```

It's kinda like a hybrid macvlan+NAT(bridge networking) approach, I guess. Anyway, would it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ​Docker, the ​macvlan network driver allows you to assign a ​MAC address and consequently an ​IP address to a ​container's virtual network interface, making it appear as a standard device on your network. Each container attached to a macvlan network is provided its unique IP address that can be reached within the LAN and potentially from external networks, depending on your network's configuration.

However, based on the Docker documentation and standard practice, the macvlan network does not provide a mechanism to assign an IP address shared across a group of containers in the way you've described -- where multiple containers essentially behave as one with a single IP address on a macvlan network. Each container on the macvlan network generally gets its own unique IP address.

The main reason for this is that an IP address is associated with a network interface, and each container gets its virtual network interface when connected to a macvlan network. The method you've described, attempting to move the IP address assignment from the service level to the network definition, would not work because the IP address assignment must be done on a per-container (per-service) basis. Docker's macvlan does not currently support assigning a single IP to multiple containers as it breaks the fundamental design of IP networking -- one IP per network interface -- which macvlan adheres to.

Macvlan driver in Docker is mainly for scenarios where you want your containers to appear as physical hosts on the network, each with its own IP address, rather than sharing a single IP. If you need multiple services (containers) to be accessed via a single IP, you would typically put them behind a load balancer or a reverse proxy that would manage the incoming traffic to the individual containers based on your configuration (ports, paths, etc.).

Your best option, if you want to have a static IP for a group of services, would be to configure an external device or service such as a load balancer or a reverse proxy to have the static IP and forward the requests to the appropriate containers on their respective IP addresses assigned by the macvlan. This keeps each container with its unique IP while presenting a unified front via the static IP of the load balancer.

If you are using Docker for Mac or Windows, you should note that there is an ongoing limitation where macvlan networks do not allow the host itself to communicate with the macvlan-connected containers due to how network namespaces are implemented. This can be worked around on Linux hosts by creating a macvlan interface on the host, as suggested on GitHub, but such a workaround may not be applicable or may require different steps on other OSes.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I tried here and there, sometimes it works. Unfortunately many of these service sets rely on this DNS-type thing to communicate among themselves, hardcoded. This and having to rescue files to when during host migration are the two reasons why I don't like `compose`. :/ So, I'm stuck, huh? At least now I won't waste time chasing after the impossible, a million thanks.